# Ruby -- capitalize first letter of every sentence in a paragraph

Tags: ruby, string

Using Ruby language, I would like to capitalize the first letter of every sentence, and also get rid of any space before the period at the end of every sentence. Nothing else should change.

```
Input =  "this is the First Sentence . this is the Second Sentence ."    
Output =  "This is the First Sentence. This is the Second Sentence."
```

Thank you folks.

Comment: How do you define the "period at the end of every sentence"? For example, which of the periods in this string are "at the end of a sentence": "The . character is used in object oriented languages a lot. You might say Dog.bark, or Cat.meow, and even, in a very perverse language, Cow. (the method name is a space here.) Or you might not... ouch, stop hitting me."

Answer (score 7):

Using regular expression ([`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)):

```
Input =  "this is the First Sentence . this is the Second Sentence ."    
Input.gsub(/[a-z][^.?!]*/) { |match| match[0].upcase + match[1..-1].rstrip }
# => "This is the First Sentence. This is the Second Sentence."

Input.gsub(/([a-z])([^.?!]*)/) { $1.upcase + $2.rstrip }  # Using capturing group
# => "This is the First Sentence. This is the Second Sentence."
```

I assumed the setence ends with `.`, `?`, `!`.

**UPDATE**

```
input = "TESTest me is agreat. testme 5 is awesome"
input.gsub(/([a-z])((?:[^.?!]|\.(?=[a-z]))*)/i) { $1.upcase + $2.rstrip }
# => "TESTest me is agreat. Testme 5 is awesome"

input = "I'm headed to stackoverflow.com"
input.gsub(/([a-z])((?:[^.?!]|\.(?=[a-z]))*)/i) { $1.upcase + $2.rstrip }
# => "I'm headed to stackoverflow.com"
```

Comment: @roytoy wants to get rid of any space before the period at the end of every sentence.

Comment: Nice solution, maybe you wanna replace `([^.?!]+)` with `([^.?!]*)`? Think about input: "i. robot."

Comment: What if the string is `this is stackoverflow.com`? the `.com` will change to `.Com`

Comment: @user3188544, Alternative: `'this is stackoverflow.com'.gsub(/(^|\s)([a-z])([^.?!]*)/) { $1 + $2.upcase + $3.rstrip }`

Comment: @falsetru Not quite... `I'm headed to stackoverflow.com` would become `I'm Headed to stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @user3188544, You're right. Here's another alternative that use positive lookahead: `/([a-z])((?:[^.?!]|\.(?=[a-z]))*)/i`

Comment: @chrishough, `[a-z,A-Z]` will match `,` in addition to alphabets. If you want to match alphabet case-insensitively you'd better to use `/.../i` modifier.

Comment: @falsetru so for something like  "TESTest me is agreat. testme 5 is awesome" I went with test.humanize.gsub(/([a-zA-Z])([^.?!]*)/) { $1.upcase + $2.rstrip }  => does that look right to you?

Comment: @chrishough, Please see my comment that got a vote. It handle another case what OP asked in the comment, not only yours.  I updated the answer to include the new expression in the comment to be part of the answer.

Comment: @falsetru thank you so much for your help, have a great weekend.

Answer (score 1):

```
Input.split('.').map(&:strip).map { |s|
  s[0].upcase + s[1..-1] + '.'
}.join(' ')
=> "This is the First Sentence. This is the Second Sentence."
```

My second approach is cleaner but produces a slightly different output:

```
Input.split('.').map(&:strip).map(&:capitalize).join('. ') + '.'
=> "This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence."
```

I'm not sure if you're fine with it.

Comment: What about sentences that ends with ?, !?

Comment: Not worried about sentences ending in ? or !

Comment: @ram After carefully reading the question, I think he should be fine with assuming every sentence ends with period.